# Searching for first duplicate element in huge array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Trying to solve this question - 
Given an array `a` that contains only numbers in the range from 1 to `a.length`, find the first duplicate number for which the second occurrence has the minimal index.

Here's my solution -

```js
function firstDuplicate(a) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a.indexOf(a[i]) !== i) {
      return a[i];
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Problem - one of the acceptance criteria is, algorithm should find the first duplicate value in under 4 seconds, which I am not able to achieve when input array is huge. I tested with input array that has 100k items in it and my algorithm took 5+ seconds. Can someone help me tweak my code so it would finish in under 4 seconds?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Like this?
 `let dupe = arr.find((k,i) => arr.indexOf(k) !==i);`

Comment: Used a set to add unique items. That works way faster

`function firstDuplicate(a) {
  var uniques = new Set();
  for(let item of a) {
    if(uniques.has(item)) {
      return item;
    } else {
      uniques.add(item);
    }
  }
  return -1;
}`

Comment: Use a map and store the count. If the map contains a key with count more than 1 then return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function firstDuplicate(a) {
  r = new Set();
  for (e of a) {
    if (r.has(e)) return e;
    else r.add(e);
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Here's how I solved it.

Comment: I've solved too and made comparison. Check my answer, it might be interesting (:

Comment: I added another option which as per JSBench seems to be more performant.

Answer (score 1):

You've to walk through that array and collect elements to temporary object that keeps number (element) as key and some boolean value as index.

On every iteration check that temporary object has that key.

```js
const bigArray = [];


for(let i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {
  bigArray.push(i);
}


for(let i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {
  bigArray.push(parseInt(Math.random()*1000000));
}


const firstDuplicateInArray = array => {
  const temp = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (temp[array[i]] === true) {
      return array[i];
    }
    temp[array[i]] = true;
  }
  return -1;
};

const start = new Date().getTime();
console.log('Time start:', start);

console.log('Found 1st duplicate:', firstDuplicateInArray(bigArray));

const end = new Date().getTime();
console.log('Time end:', end);

console.log('Time taken:', end - start, 'microseconds');
```

P.S. `Set` more than 2 times slower (depending on size of array):

```js
const bigArray = [];


for(let i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {
  bigArray.push(i);
}


for(let i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {
  bigArray.push(parseInt(Math.random()*1000000));
}


function firstDuplicate(a) {
  const r = new Set();
  for (let e of a) {
    if (r.has(e)) return e;
    else r.add(e);
  }
  return -1;
}

const start = new Date().getTime();
console.log('Time start:', start);

console.log('Found 1st duplicate:', firstDuplicate(bigArray));

const end = new Date().getTime();
console.log('Time end:', end);

console.log('Time taken:', end - start, 'microseconds');
```

Comment: The negation is clever.  Others should note:  when a problem limits integer values to the problem size, it almost always means you should use an array of that size as a set or map keyed on those values.

Comment: @num8er your using different random test data in the two scripts which doesn't give us  1 to 1 comparison. In my testing it about as fast as the Set version, because your effectively using a hashing structure too (object) as currently listed.  Try `const temp = new Array(array.length);` ...

Comment: @spinkus I know. My goal by doing this was making enough big array where that duplicate element could be very far from beginning. To test performance with array solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Set` is going to result in key collisions. Since you know your values are integers in a bounded range the fastest way is to use a direct index, which requires `O(1)` lookup time instead of `O(lg n)`. Although, the straight forward implementation will require `2*n` storage. If you are able to mutate the input array you could use it as your working space:

```js
// No extra memory version.
// Negate value at index of seen number to store seen-ness.
// Assumes only numbers in the range from 1 to a.length allowed in array `a`.    
function firstDuplicateNew(a) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    v = Math.abs(a[i])
    if (a[v-1] < 0) {
      return a[i];
    }
    a[v-1] = -1*a[v-1];
  }
  return -1;
}

// OP's Proposed faster version using Set.
function firstDuplicateSet(a) {
  r = new Set();
  for (e of a) {
    if (r.has(e)) return e;
    else r.add(e);
  }
  return -1;
}

// Another posted version.
const firstDuplicateInArray = array => {
  const temp = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (temp[array[i]] === true) {
      return array[i];
    }
    temp[array[i]] = true;
  }
  return -1;
};

a = []
l = 5e6
// for(i = 0; i<l;i++){ a.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*l)); }
for(i = 0; i<l;i++){ a[i] = i+1; }
a[l-1] = 7

for(f of [firstDuplicateSet, firstDuplicateInArray, firstDuplicateNew])      {
  then = Date.now()
  i = f(a)
  now = Date.now()
  console.log(f.name ? f.name : '-')
  console.log('Len:', a.length)
  console.log('Value:'+i)
  console.log('Time:', now-then+'ms')
}
```

Seems to run much faster than other versions.

Answer (score 0):

If fast processing time is a must, I'd deem it worth to spend some memory in the algorithm:

Simply create a *reverse map*: an array as big as the range of stored numbers. Then, browse the input array and store in the reverse map the index corresponding to each number. And when you find that this number has been already indexed, you got your duplicated number.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using indexOf which is O(n) runtime, use a dictionary to store key/value pairs, with the key being the number and the value being the index. It can be accessed in O(1) time and you will only need one pass through the array. If your key has an undefined value, you know you haven't seen it yet, otherwise, the first key you find with an actual value must be the first duplicate and that value is the minimal index.